# How to remove NA values in analysis of errors

Tags: r, na, lm, data-fitting

I need to fit a finance time series and make an analysis of errors. 
I have fit the series with a linear model.

```
library("quantmod")
library("zoo")

getSymbols("DJIA", src="FRED")
class(DJIA)

serie = DJIA["2017/2018"]
price = as.numeric(serie)
time  = index(serie)


x=1:length(price)
model = lm(price~x)
reg = model$coef[1]+model$coef[2]*x

plot(x=time, y=price, main="Dow Jones", type="l", xlab="Data", ylab="Points")
lines(time, reg, col=2, lwd=2)
```

My series has NA values. Below you can see the first value is `NA`.

```
head(serie)

> head(serie)
               DJIA
2017-01-02       NA
2017-01-03 19881.76
2017-01-04 19942.16
2017-01-05 19899.29
2017-01-06 19963.80
2017-01-09 19887.38
```

I have tried to use the function `na.StructTS()` from the `zoo` package.

```
serie_out <- na.StructTS(serie, na.rm=TRUE)

# Error in StructTS(y) :
# the first value of the time series must not be missing
```

Edit.

```
serie_out <- na.StructTS(serie[-1,], na.rm=TRUE)

#    Error in rowSums(tsSmooth(StructTS(y))[, -2]) :
#      'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

**Question.**

How can I work with `NA` values in finance time series?

I can move the start period from 2017-01-02 to 2017-01-03 but the  series has several `NA`s.

Comment: why not simply start with the second entry: `serie_out <- na.StructTS(serie[-1,],  na.rm=TRUE)`?

Comment: serie_out <- na.StructTS(serie[-1,], na.rm=TRUE)
Error in rowSums(tsSmooth(StructTS(y))[, -2]) :
'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions